# Overwrite template-tags.php in child theme

Tags: themes, templates, child-theme

I would like to overwrite some content which is located in (`inc/`) `template-tags.php` file on parent theme.

Content need to be changed is in function `footer_content_widget_area` in `template-tags.php` file and that function is called on `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'page_widgets', 'footer_content_widget_area' );
```

Comment: How does the parent theme load the file `template-tags.php`?

Comment: It is loaded in custom function in functions.php.

Answer (score 0):

In `functions.php` child theme include `template-tags.php` from parent theme:

```
require_once get_theme_file_path( '../parent-theme/inc/template-tags.php' );
```

In the child theme  `template-tags.php` remove parent action and add the child action replacing it:

```
remove_action( 'tag', 'parent-function', 0 );
add_action( 'tag', 'new-child-function', 10 );
```

Answer (score -1):

As long as you have a child-theme setup correctly then you just allow the child-theme to replace the parent-theme template by placing the template file in the same location.

So based on the location that you mention in your question you would simply place your edited copy of the template-tags.php in the location **child-theme/inc/**

the wordpress way of things is explained in the Template_Hierarchy (https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).